# Send phone call to POTS with computer software

Tags: pots

Looking for a solution for a customer who does not use internet, and needs to send a call from the computer to clients. meaning that the computer should send a command to the phone to start a call from the physical phone.

Not using the PC for call mic & audio. using the PC only to send phone call to the physical phone, and then continue speaking over the phone.

Anyone knows to recommend which hardware is needed for that?

Comment: Will this: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B077YBTC2J help me?

Comment: If your phone line can switch from PC to your phone during a call that part is definitely a step in the right direction

Comment: will PABX help for that?

Comment: I don't know, I am not super experienced with physical phone lines

Answer (score 0):

You need [asterisk](https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-auto-dial-out/) to make outgoing calls for voice not data.

For POTS lines, you need [analog cards](https://www.sangoma.com/products/network-connectivity/telephony-cards/analog-cards/).